# Просуммировать числа, встречающиеся в строке

Tags: c#

Написал следующий код, требовалось просуммировать числа, встречающиеся в строке.
В данном коде я использовал лишь сумму цифр. Подскажите пожалуйста, как учитывать минус при суммировании цифр, и как можно выполнять сумму чисел, а не только цифр.

```
string s = Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
   if (Char.IsDigit(s[i]))
   {
      string s2 = Convert.ToString(s[i]);
      sum += int.Parse(s2);
   }
}

textBox2.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: что значит "как учитывать минус"? у вас в строке встречаются отрицательные числа? что значит "выполнять сумму чисел, а не только цифр"? не помешал бы пример входных данных

Comment: А какой смысл в этой строке: `string s = Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);` ? `string` в `string` ?

Comment: А какие входные строки могут быть? Какие разделители между цифрами, числами?

Comment: Цифра - 1,2,3,4.... Число 12,52,42....
Да, требуется учитывать отрицательные числа. 
Входные строки: фывф2фыв23фыв1выв4 - в сумме дают 12.
фывф2фыв23фыв1выв-4 - в сумме дают 12, хотя должно быть 4. (т.к. -4)

Comment: Перенесите ваше уточнение из комментария в текст вопроса ([править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/846566/edit))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для определения числа эффективно использовать регулярное выражение, например, вот это `/-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g`. Под данное выражение подойдут просто числа, отрицательные числа и дробные числа (`1554`, `-547`, `85.32`). Если дробную часть числа необходимо разделять `,`, а не `.`, то в регулярном выражении замените, в середине, запятую на точку. Также надо будет убрать `.Replace()` в `foreach()`.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "7fe2dyj2rd923u203k 2n 2 3283-234 fm,kld550.9";
            double sum = 0;

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?");

            foreach(var match in matches)
            {
                sum += Convert.ToDouble(match.ToString().Replace('.', ','));
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Сумма: {sum}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как насчет LINQ? ```var sum = Regex.Matches(input, @"-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?").Cast<Match>().Select(x => Convert.ToDouble(x.Value.Replace('.', ','))).Sum();```

Comment: @gregzakharov Слишком круто) Добавьте как ответ, хороший вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала требуется определиться с помощью чего у вас разделаяется ввод чисел. Например числа вводятся через запятую:

```
var numbers = s.Split(',').Select(n => Int32.Parse(n)).ToArray();
```

В переменной numbers у нас появляется массив чисел(с учётом знака). Далее с помощью цикла складываем их и получаем результат:

```
var sum = 0;
foreach (var number in numbers)
{
    sum += number;
}
```